# Writing software for the RPi without hardware (Mocking/Stubbing)

Tags: python, python-3, commercial-use

I have an IoT project that uses the Pi Zero W and at some point want to utilize the compute modules for industrial application.  Currently, doing dev I may use a RPi 3/4 to copy files across and run code (mainly b/c its faster than the Zero).  However, it is a pretty slow and a painful dev experience.  It works and have taken the project quite far with it but I am wanting to improve the enjoyment aspect of it.

Is there a standard practice for stubbing/mocking modules like the `RPi.GPIO` and Adafruits `adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel` module. I did run across this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/willbuckner/rpi-gpio-development-mock/blob/master/RPi/GPIO.py) for mocking RPI.gpio and will probably use it but wanted to see if there was something I am just *missing*. Just curious if people would dev against the mock, like the linked repo above, and then only just exclude the local mocked module when transferring to the RPi?

Coming from a software centric background, I am not quite sure how the community really unit tests all aspects of there application?  Is there something similar to a mobile IOS/Android simulator...where you can still do all development on the host machine but not be limited to kind of blindly coding and moving them along to the RPi device.

Comment: Simplest way I found is to develop on the Pi by using VS Code and it's remote execution / debug though it means you have a Pi networked all the time.  Bit of a pain with GUI development with one monitor though :-(

Comment: Someone created a neopixel emulator here; https://github.com/rogerdahl/WS2812B-NeoPixel-Emulator

Comment: @Andyroo Thanks for the recommendation!  I just started trying the remote execution today and it certainly feels way nicer.  Never realized vscode even supported remote execution but definitely glad you seen this post, thanks!

Comment: From my searching, I don't think many people bother mocking things on RPi. I'd like to mock adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel myself. I might mash up one of the available emulators so the mock will cause it to display a virtual LED display on the pc screen.